# How to initialise linear relation in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, initialization

Let's say I want to approximate some unknown function y=f(x) on x=[lb,ub] with AI. So I thought of using two layers, with 100 nodes each. I want to initialize the neural network with a linear relation, say with slope 'S' and intercept 'C', because that will be a good approximation in the middle of the domain.

EDIT:
How should I initialize the neural network with the linear relationship? Because a linear initialization seems crucial as the approximation now is not good (using relu doesn't change much).

Here is the model:

```
 def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1,n_nodes_hl1], 
    stddev=0.01)),
    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_nodes_hl1], 
     stddev=0.01))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2], 
    stddev=0.01)),
    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_nodes_hl2], 
    stddev=0.01))}

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_nodes_hl2,n_classes], stddev=0.01)),

    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_classes], 
     stddev=0.01))}


     # (input_data * weights) + biases
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), 
    hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.softsign(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), 
    hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.softsign(l2)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, output_layer['weights']), 
    output_layer['biases'])

return output
```

I honestly have now clue how to do that, because the neural network is pretty much a black box to me. 
(Any other suggestions for better models for function approximation are also welcome).

Comment: The NN seems to be good. Try using the `tf.nn.relu` function instead of `tf.nn.softsign`.

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamPanchal but the question is how to initialize the NN with a linear relationship, because that seems crucial to learn the function. The results now are not even close...